# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL instance

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm currently setting up a Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL database and connection fails every single time. I've remade the Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL instance 3x now, both with default out of the box settings and custom settings, and even tried putting creds on pgAdmin, no dice. I've tested another database connection and it works just fine.

I'm setting it to be public accessible as well, with username and database both just "postgres". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "I'm setting it to be public accessible as well" You still have to open the Security Group port if trying to connect from outside the VPC. Did you do that?

Comment: Default security group, all IPs, yes.